# Cannot program Google Coral Dev Board through Arduino on Windows 10

Tags: arduino, upload, windows-10, google-coral

I can see the Coral Dev Board through the serial interface / putty, and it does show as Universal Serial Bus devices/'USB download gadget', in Windows 10 device manager. But when I try to download a program through Arduino (it compiles fine), I get the following error message when entering uploading:

```
[15748] Failed to execute script 'flashtool' due to unhandled exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flashtool.py", line 16, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'progress'
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I can nowhere find a reference to a 'flashtool' in any manual for this board, or online. How to fix this?

I reinstalled the Coral board in Arduino, and retried compiling & uploading several times, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The flashtool.py script requires a couple of Python packages to be installed.
Just to a

```
pip install progress
```

You will further need to install a couple of other required packages as well to run the Script.

Comment: Thank you. I might try at a later moment. Meanwhile I bought a Coral Dev Board Micro, which works with Arduino right out of the box. Strange that Coral didn't implement Arduino programming by default for the first released Dev Board, and the Mini version.